# How to open a file in "append" mode using open ? fopen?

Tags: c, file, file-io

In order to write to a new file , I do the following  :

```
// some code 
...

 pfd[i][0] = open(argv[j+1],O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0600);
```

Questions :

1. Is there a difference between using `open` or `fopen` ?
2. How can I use `open` for opening an existing file in `append` mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `open` is for POSIX systems. It is not portable to other system. `fopen` is part of C standard, so it will work on all C implementation. I am ignoring the difference that `open` returns a file descriptor where `fopen` returns a `FILE *`.
2. Use `O_APPEND` to open for append mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. The difference is that `open` is a non-portable, POSIX function and `fopen` is portable, standard C function.
2. Specify `O_APPEND` when calling `open` to use append mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use `O_APPEND`

quote from `open()` description in [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

> O_APPEND
>      If set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes. There is a diference: **Buffered or non-buffered I/O.**
`open()` gives to you a RAW file handle (there isn´t a buffer between your program and the file in the file system).

`fopen()` gives to you the permission to work with files in stream buffer mode. For example, you can read/write data line-by-line (\0).

You can see the big diference when work with functions like: `fprintf()`, `fscanf()`, `fgets()`, `fflush()`.

ps: `fopen()` isn´t better than `open()`. They are different things. Some times you need stream buffer (fopen), some times you need work byte-by-byte (open).

Here is a good reference about stream: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node18.html#SECTION001820000000000000000

2) To open in append mode, add `O_APPEND` flag:

`open(argv[j+1],O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY,0600);`